# Which article do I use with "class" and "the name of a certain subject" when talking about a certain class in general?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Tell me please which article I have to use before *class* and the name of a certain subject in general, not about one specific class? For example:

> I like going to English class.
>
> I like going to **an** English class.
>
> I like going to **the** English class.

Does any of the sentences sound natural? Would the following be better?

> I like going to English classes.

Answer (score 0):

I like going to English classes (General use)

I like going to an English class (Many English classes are going on, you like going to one class among them)

I like going to the English classes (particular English class)

Comment: What kind of grammar is that "to an English classes"?

Comment: an error, perhaps a typo, which I've fixed